# IPX/SPX Protocol

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 system and want to install IPX/SPX protocol on it, since Microsoft have stopped supporting IPX protocol.So is there any work around to get IPX protocol on Windows Server 2008 R2.need it for testing purpose.

Comment: I know the "how-to" on this question has already been answered, but for my own curiosity, why in the world would you want to do this?

Comment: On second thought, I'm rescinding my answer because you just should not do this. There is no good reason to do this.

Comment: A client of mine requires this, he told me find any solution for these issue..

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions.

Comment: @user168692 - You have two options: 1) Tell your client his request is completely unreasonable and that he needs to be open to other options or 2) Drop that client.

Comment: Maybe this client keeps trying to find a consultant to help him, and they keep coming to SF?

Comment: @mfinni so we should wrap up for more "IPX on Server 2008 R2" questions? Heaven forbid!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to reference this excellent answer from the [Microsoft support forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/479f3191-01c7-4a84-8b45-57e2f73bbf6b/) which has been given in April of ***2009***, over 4 years ago:

> No. Microsoft stopped natively supporting IPX 6 years ago with the
>   release of Win2003 (see:
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784723.aspx).
>
> Novell stopped supporting IPX with the release of Windows Vista two
>   years ago. From their Novell Client SP1 documentation:
>
> http://www.novell.com/documentation/vista_client/vista_client_admin/index.html?page=/documentation/vista_client/vista_client_admin/data/b87phor.html
>
> 1.2.1 Novell Client for Windows XP/2003 Features Not Included in the Novell Client for Windows Vista
>
> The following Novell Client for Windows XP/2003 features are not included in the Novell Client for
>   Windows Vista:
>
> `<snip>`
>
> - IPX/SPX™ protocols and API libraries.
>
> `</snip>`

Comment: Good answer - though you might as well post it again over on his previous duplicate question...